# Node.js: Connection between servers

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have question, this might be small but I've not found answer anywhere.

Do we need to have a port address for a node.js server to connect to other node.js server and create a communication between them or can we connect in any other way without using port address?

Comment: are those node servers on the same machine?

Comment: Yes, for now they are in the same machine.

Comment: you might be able to use unix domain sockets as long as they're on the same machine

Comment: Can you please tell me how to use unix domain sockets...??

Comment: I'm not sure how you'd do it in nodejs. There's documentation about how to do the client, but I can't find any on how to do the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, you need a port number** to talk over the Internet with another Server. Since you cannot send raw IP packets (your server wouldn't allow it), you want to use a transport protocol like TCP or UDP (TCP allows stateful connections while UDP is stateless) which both require a port number to distinct the process on the destination server.

Any application protocol like the Hyper Text Transfer Protocol (HTTP) uses a transport protocol to carry the payload. This abstraction is defined as [OSI layers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_layer).

Comment: eww, nobody uses OSI anymore

Comment: Well, layers 5, 6 and 7 (session, presentation and application) are most often not distinguishable because the OSI layers are an abstract model created before knowing the requirements. But as far as I know, all protocols conform to this model.

Comment: Is there any way that I can implement a Discover protocol [Node-discover] such that it might able to discover the running nodejs processes? I've thought I can implement if I connect the node.js servers without using the port number. Is there any other way to do it?,

Comment: @DavidCzihak: As far as I know, BGP (which is layer-3-ish) sits on top of UDP (which would be layer-4-ish).

Comment: @thejh BGP is an application-layer protocol (layer 7) to exchange routing information between routers which is then used to route IP packets (layer 3). BGP relies on TCP [(Reference)](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_BGPMessageGenerationandTransportandGeneralMessageF.htm) and is not involved in the actual routing of IP packets.

Comment: @prakash On the same server? It is possible to query the port, for example via DNS [SRV records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record). But of course, that's for IP connections, not IPC (inter-process communication).

Comment: ummmm, it is like for example I have 4 node.js servers performing different operations, I want them to discover [(node-discover)](https://github.com/wankdanker/node-discover) each other and establish a communication link between them[Inter- process communication]

Comment: I thought a lot about the problem, and I managed to write a node.js application that auto-discovers other instances and connects to them via a UNIX domain socket. But before I share my results with you, why would you possibly want multiple instances on one server?

Comment: I am trying to implement something with the nodes where it has auto discovery such that it automatically discovers the nodes and get connected to them. And I am not trying to have multiple instances on one server, I have multiple servers that handle its own operations.

Comment: Let all servers join a multicast group and use multicast messages for discovery.

Comment: I've got a discovery process using UDP and multicast group, Thank you. But still I am lack of establishing a communication link between each node.